# Unlock fingerprint Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, device-policy-manager

i have done previously resting password using `DevicePolicyManager`  which was working fine .The same app recently i have installed with fingerprint lock devices through sms  but my app not able to unlock fingerprint.Is there any android code is available to reset fingerprint?

```
public class DemoDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
  DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        this.devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService("device_policy");
        this.devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", 1);

    }

}
```

Refereed following document :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html